# Coding to interfaces

Tags: c#, design

I understand why it is a good idea to code to an interface rather than to a concrete class. I find it hard to implement though as other methods generally need to use properties of the given object. Have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: You can use auto-implemented properties and getter methods, should you need them e.g. `int someId { get; set; }` works. That said, full consideration should be made as to whether the property should be part of the interface.

Comment: Keep it simple - Don't use something because it is better. Use what you know is necessary to do the job right.

Comment: Okay but were they talking about interfaces as in class APIs or interfaces the construct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why needing properties matters. Don't focus on what you need to perform the operation, but rather what operations are needed. The data needed to perform said operations will be determined by the implementing classes.

For example, you have a `Shape` interface. One of the methods in this interface is `getArea()`. You say that anything that is a `Shape` must be able to calculate its area - that implies that it must have the appropriate properties and members to do so. If a `Circle` class implements the shape interface and needs a `getArea()` method, that implies that (since `getArea()` doesn't take any parameters), that the `Circle` instance must be aware of it's radius. If a `Rectangle` class implements the `Shape` interface, that implies that it must somehow maintain its length and width.

Comment: So if I have another class that uses the radius property is the class incorrect? In the example im currently working on I need to update a status and Activation date then save. Should I impliment  ChangeStatus and a ChangeActivationDate methods instead?

Comment: @Tom Squires Do all classes (now and potential future) that would implement this interface have the ability to change their status and/or activation date? If these methods are taking parameters, would all classes that implement this interface take the same parameters when changing status and/or activation date?

Comment: status yes, activation date no. I currently have diffrent types of request that inherit from one abstract request. Im thinking the interface should be on request not say orderRequest. Is that right?

Comment: @TomSquires If you have a class hierarchy of requests, then the capability to change request can go into the interface, as long as you have it accept the highest possible class in the request class hierarchy. Then, each class can validate the arguments to ensure that it can handle it, using return types and/or exceptions to deal with invalid data.

Answer (score 2):

In the case where you need external access to a property of an object you should make it part of the interface.  The usual convention is to add set_foo() and get_foo() methods to provide this access.

It is fairly common to need a few getter and setter functions, but you should think about the interface before adding too many.  In particular you should make sure that the property is a property of the class, not of the implementation.  Don't expose implementation details outside of the class, only properties which will **always** be a part of any reasonable implementation of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Think of interface conformance as a step beyond type safety. Identify things that are changed  and ways they can be changed, define interface that provides them all and then while writing to interface assures you don't worry you'll confuse parameters or mess up units.

You can always assign special meta-values for "Do not affect" or "Not applicable", stubs that discard unnecessary information or provide blanket "default" values if your interface is "on the large side". But you're better off if you use more granular, smaller interfaces to cover smaller chunks of functionality. It will be better to separately implement "work data" and "configuration" interfaces, than requiring implementation of one huge "input data" interface, or even split "work data" further for various sources/types, like Activation and Status being separate interfaces - classes that need both, implement both.